# number of records between two dates phpmysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code to get records between two dates `$date1` and `$date2`

```
for ($i=$date1;$i<$date2;$i++){//BETWEEN THE TWO DATES
        $count_rcvd=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from cards where Date_Rcvd='$i'"));
        $count_collect=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from cards where Date_Collected='$i'"));
        if($i==$date1){FOR THE FIRST DATE IN THE RANGE
        $uncollected=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from cards where Status='AVAILABLE' and Date_Rcvd<='$i'"));
        $balance=$uncollected;
    }
    else{//FOR CONSECUTIVE DATES AFTER DATE1
    $uncollected=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from cards where Status='AVAILABLE' and Date_Rcvd<'$i'"));//previous days balance
    $balance=$uncollected+$count_rcvd-$count_collect;
```

When i echo for $i
      echo "";
      echo $i;
      echo "";
      echo $count_rcvd;
      echo "";
      echo $count_collect;
      echo "";
      echo $balance;
      echo "";

I get out below with the date going well beyond the calender dates

```
014-03-15   0   7   103
2014-03-16  0   3   100
2014-03-17  0   7   96
2014-03-18  0   9   94
2014-03-19  0   5   98
2014-03-20  15  6   112
2014-03-21  0   6   103
2014-03-22  0   1   108
2014-03-23  0   0   109
2014-03-24  0   8   101
2014-03-25  0   3   106
2014-03-26  0   0   109
2014-03-27  1   2   108
2014-03-28  0   0   110
2014-03-29  6   1   115
2014-03-30  0   0   116
2014-03-31  0   0   116
2014-03-32  0   0   116
2014-03-33  0   0   116
2014-03-34  0   0
```

the problem is the output dates go beyond 31st for example....HELP!!!

Comment: You should repair your question's code, there are parts missing...

Comment: What's your question? And your PHP is incomplete (where does the `else` come from?)

Comment: Ok, what output do you want?! What's your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To iterate on dates, i recommand you to use DateTime and DateTimeInterval classes (Be careful ! PHP 5.3 minimum) : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php

You can add days/months following the real calendar : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.add.php